# Add SSH Connection with pem key to Apache Airflow connection

Tags: python, ssh, airflow

Is there a way to add an ssh connection to Apache Airflow from the UI either via connections or vairables tab that allow connection using a pem key and not a username and password.

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER: Following answer is purely speculative*

- I think [`key_file`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py#L49) param of `SSHHook` is meant for this purpose
- And the idiomatic way to supply it is to pass it's name via [`extra`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py#L102) args in `Airflow` `Connection` entry (web UI)

---

- Of course when neither `key_file` nor *credentials* are provided, then `SSHHook` [falls back](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py#L140) to `identityfile` to initialize `paramiko` client.
- Also have a look how `SFTPHook` is [handling this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py#L83)